# Update constraints in Database - Grails 3.2.2

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-orm

I had a class with a `String` field and now I have added a new constraint:

```
foo(maxSize: 30)
```

In my `dataSource` I have this value:

```
dbCreate: update
```

And when I run the app the `maxSize` does not change in my database (checked with `MySql Workbench`).

How can I update new constraints in database?

Comment: I guess: underlying Hibernate (behaviour typical for main JPA providers) has 'update' mode, but always ducumentan say 'not use in production'. Usually can add column, but not change constraints, add indexes etc...

Comment: Take a look at the database migration plugin, http://plugins.grails.org/plugin/grails/database-migration

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GORM` does not alter the existing column, when using `dataSource.dbCreate = update`. You should do it by yourself, using `alter table` statement.

The best option, imo, is to use the `migrations` plugin; it is recently published. You can read the guide in [here](http://guides.grails.org/grails-database-migration/guide/index.html). Plugin documentation is available [here](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-database-migration/3.0.x/index.html).

I suggest you to read the guide and refer to the documentation, provided above.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `dbCreate: create-drop`, if affordable..., I mean suitable, for your situation.